# nested resources / controller / view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Appartment controller:

```
@appartment = Appartment.find(params[:id])
@amenities = @appartment.amenities
```

Model Appartment:

```
has_many :amenity_appartment
has_many :amenities, :through => :amenity_appartment
```

Model Amenity

```
has_many :amenity_appartment
has_many :appartments, :through => :amenity_appartment
belongs_to :category_amenity
```

Model CategoryAmenity

```
has_many :amenities
```

To show the amenities of the apartment I have this:

```
<% @amenities.each do |amenity| %>
    <p><%= amenity.name %></p>
```

I get a nice list of all the amenities, but can I separate this by the name of `category_amenity`?

Comment: What do you mean by separating it by the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort amenities by category in your controller first:

```
@amenities = {}
@appartment.amenities.each do |a|
  @amenities[a.category_amenity.name] ||= []
  @amenities[a.category_amenity.name] << a
end
```

and to show them:

```
<% @amenities.each do |category_name, vals| %>
    <p><%= category_name %></p>
    <% vals.each do |amenity| %>
      ....
```